# Using recurrences to solve $3a^2=2b^2+1$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, recurrence-relations, diophantine-equations, pell-type-equations

Is it possible to solve the equation $3a^2=2b^2+1$ for positive, integral $a$ and $b$ using recurrences?I am sure it is, as Arthur Engel in his Problem Solving Strategies has stated that as a method, but I don't think I understand what he means.Can anyone please tell me how I should go about it?Thanks.
Edit:Added the condition that $a$ and $b$ are positive integers.

Comment: Which part? Which page? Section?

Comment: Page number 154, solution to Problem 137 in the number theory section.

Comment: See also [page 147](http://books.google.com/books?id=sqqrD2W_ClMC&pg=PA147), solution of 92(b). Both occurrences are after Pell's equation.

Comment: So, it turns out I don't even know how to solve the Pell's equation.!

Comment: If you have access to this book, Section 3.2 _Solving Pell's Equation_ in the book An Introduction to Diophantine Equations: A Problem-Based Approach  By Titu Andreescu, Dorin Andrica, Ion Cucurezeanu should contain more than enough information on Pell's equation. See [p.121](http://books.google.com/books?id=D_XmfolL-IUC&pg=PA121). Maybe you don't even have to go through the proofs, it should be enough if you understand what the results claim and practice them on a few concrete examples.

Comment: Other useful resources to learn about Pell's equation could be:
http://www.imomath.com/tekstkut/pelleqn_ddj.pdf,
http://www.artofproblemsolving.com/Wiki/index.php/Pell_equation and,
of cousrse, [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pell%27s_equation). And, very probably, for solution of this exercises the facts mentioned in Engel's book should be sufficient.

Comment: Thank you very much for the links.I should be able to "take over" from here.Thanks again for searching that for me.(I should have probably done that myself instead of troubling people here)

Comment: @Sabyasachi: This is a question-answer site, so the intention is that people come here and ask. (Just reacting to your comment: _I should have probably done that myself instead of troubling people here._ I do not think you're troubling anyone.)

Comment: A new question about the same equation, although a solution using the hint from Engel's books has not been posted yet: [Solve the Diophantine equation $3x^2-2y^2=1$](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/181758/solve-the-diophantine-equation-3x2-2y2-1)

Answer (score 1):

Yes. See, for example, the pair of sequences https://oeis.org/A054320 and https://oeis.org/A072256, where the solutions are listed. The recurrence is defined by $$a_0 = a_1 = 1; \qquad a_n = 10a_{n-1} - a_{n-2},\ n\ge 2.$$

As to how to go about solving this, there are many good references on how to do this, including [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recurrence_relation).

Answer (score 0):

Although it should be mentioned, and the equation: $$aX^2-qY^2=f$$

If the root of the whole: $\sqrt{\frac{f}{a-q}}$

Using equation Pell:  $$p^2-aqs^2=1$$  solutions can be written:

$$Y=(2aps\pm(p^2+aqs^2))\sqrt{\frac{f}{a-q}}$$

$$X=(2qps\pm(p^2+aqs^2))\sqrt{\frac{f}{a-q}}$$

And for that decision have to find double formula.

$$Y_2=Y+2as(qsY-pX)$$

$$X_2=X+2p(qsY-pX)$$

We will use these formulas to solve equations:  $$3X^2-2Y^2=1$$

Decisions will be determined by the Pell equation: $$p^2-6s^2=1$$

Starting from the first solution: $(p_0,s_0)$ - $(5,2)$

You can find all the rest of the formula.

$$s_2=2p_1+5s_1$$

$$p_2=5p_1+12s_1$$

These numbers will need to substitute in:

$$Y=p^2\pm6ps+6s^2$$

$$X=p^2\pm4ps+6ps$$

Then you can consider and the twins. It is necessary to take into account that all of the substitution number can have any signs.