# Representations of integers by a binary quadratic form

Tags: number-theory

Let $\mathfrak{F}$ be the set of binary quadratic forms over $\mathbb{Z}$.
Let $f(x, y) = ax^2 + bxy + cy^2 \in \mathfrak{F}$.
Let $\alpha = \left( \begin{array}{ccc}
p & q \\
r & s \end{array} \right)$ be an element of $SL_2(\mathbb{Z})$.
We write $f^\alpha(x, y) = f(px + qy, rx + sy)$.
Since $(f^\alpha)^\beta$ = $f^{\alpha\beta}$, $SL_2(\mathbb{Z})$ acts on $\mathfrak{F}$ from right.

Let $f, g \in \mathfrak{F}$.
If $f$ and $g$ belong to the same $SL_2(\mathbb{Z})$-orbit, we say $f$ and $g$ are equivalent.

Let $f = ax^2 + bxy + cy^2 \in \mathfrak{F}$.
We say $D = b^2 - 4ac$ is the discriminant of $f$.
Let $m$ be an integer.
If $m = ax^2 + bxy + cy^2$ has a solution in $\mathbb{Z}^2$, we say $m$ is represented by $ax^2 + bxy + cy^2$.
If $m = ax^2 + bxy + cy^2$ has a solution $(s, t)$ such that gcd$(s, t) = 1$,
we say $m$ is properly represented by $ax^2 + bxy + cy^2$.

Is the following proposition true?
If yes, how do we prove it?

**Proposition**
Let $ax^2 + bxy + cy^2 \in \mathfrak{F}$.
Suppose its discriminant is not a square.
Let $m$ be an integer.
Then $m$ is properly represented by $ax^2 + bxy + cy^2$ if and only if there exist integers $l, k$ such that $ax^2 + bxy + cy^2$ and $mx^2 + lxy + ky^2$ are equivalent.

Comment: Yes, of course. Take the representation of $m$ as one column of a 2 by 2 matrix and solve for the other column so as to have determinant $1.$ Call that $R$, and call the Hessian matrix of the first form $H.$ The Hessian of the new form is $R^T H R.$

Comment: Why is this question so full of notation that isn't used at all in the formulation of the actual problem?

Comment: @t.b. Because we use the definitions in my other questions and I think it's convenient for the readers having the relevant definitions in the same place.

Comment: @Makoto: ... at the cost of obscuring *this* question. I also think it unlikely that readers of your other questions will find it convenient. I don't think such a style of presentation suits this type of medium -- it would be more appropriate for, say, a book, blog, or wiki.

Comment: @Hurkyl "at the cost of obscuring this question" I think the question is clear. As for your latter comment, I believe my questions concerning binary quadratic forms are interesting and useful for most people who are interested in number theory. So I think they are on topic in this site. Please also note that there are usually several different answers to a mathematical question. Even if I have an answer, it may well not be the only one, nor a correct one. Even my question may be negative.

Comment: @Makoto: You have the advantages of already knowing the context and having recently written the post, so that *you* can easily ignore everything that isn't the actual question. t.b.'s comment lets me put words to a problem I've had with your questions previously: a large fraction of your questions I never finish reading, because they drag on and on and I lose interest before I actually get to the content of the question.

Answer (score 2):

I cannot understand the comment of William Jagy, but I think this question is in fact quite easy, and I shall employ the method using *topographs* as in [**Cnonway**'s *Sensual Quadratic Form*](http://www.maths.ed.ac.uk/~aar/papers/conwaysens.pdf).
But, once one knows what a topograph is, and some basic properties if that concept, this becomes an easy exercise.
A topograph of a quadratic form is like [image: haha].
Here the lettres mean the values represented by a form $f$. And we represent $m$ there. The condition that $m$ is properly represented implies that the representation must occur in the graph(see Conway's little book). Then, taking $h=m+x-y$, we shall find that the form $f$ is equivalent with $\langle m,h,x\rangle$, as required(see the book again). (For an example of the graph, [see the answer of Will Jagy.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/181758/solve-the-diophantine-equation-3x2-2y2-1/181812#comment743388_181812))
Conversely, if there is such a form $\langle m,h,x\rangle$ equivalent with $f$, then $f$ should also properly represent $m$, as the other form does.
Feel free to tell me where the errors are, if any; thanks in advance.
P.S. The diagram above is hand-made, and is in fact modelled on the form $X^2+4XY+Y^2$.

Answer (score 1):

**Lemma 1**
Let $f = ax^2 + bxy + cy^2 \in \mathfrak{F}$.
Let $\alpha = \left( \begin{array}{ccc}
p & q \\
r & s \end{array} \right)$ be an element of $SL_2(\mathbb{Z})$.
Then $f^\alpha(x, y) = f(px + qy, rx + sy) = kx^2 + lxy + my^2$,
where

$k = ap^2 + bpr + cr^2$

$l = 2apq + b(ps + qr) + 2crs$

$m = aq^2 + bqs + cs^2$.

Proof:
Clear.

**Proof of the proposition**
Let $f(x, y) = ax^2 + bxy + cy^2$.

Suppose $m$ is properly represented by $f(x, y)$.
There exist integers $p, r$ such that gcd$(p, r) = 1$ and $m = f(p, r)$.
Since gcd$(p, r) = 1$, there exist integers $s, r$ such that $ps - rq = 1$.
By Lemma 1, $f(px + qy, rx + sy) = mx^2 + lxy + ky^2$,
where

$m = ap^2 + bpr + cr^2$

$l = 2apq + b(ps + qr) + 2crs$

$k = aq^2 + bqs + cs^2$.

Hence, $ax^2 + bxy + cy^2$ and $mx^2 + lxy + ky^2$ are equivalent.

Conversely suppose $ax^2 + bxy + cy^2$ and $mx^2 + lxy + ky^2$ are equivalent.
There exists integer $p, q, r, s$ such that $ps - rq = 1$ and
$f(px + qy, rx + sy) = mx^2 + lxy + ky^2$.
Letting $x = 1, y = 0$, we get $f(p, r) = m$.
Since $ps - rq = 1$, gcd$(p, r) = 1$.
Hence $m$ is properly represented by $ax^2 + bxy + cy^2$.