# Binary quadratic forms over Z and class numbers of quadratic ﬁelds.

Tags: number-theory

What is the relation between the classiﬁcation of binary quadratic forms over $\mathbb Z$,  and the problem of ﬁnding the class numbers of quadratic ﬁelds?

What would be a nice reference for this?

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/192217/bijection-between-an-ideal-class-group-and-a-set-of-classes-of-binary-quadratic

Answer (score 11):

For a very beautiful, modern, and general treatment, see [this paper](http://arxiv.org/abs/1007.5285) of Melanie Matchett Wood.  The classical comparison is explained at the beginning of the paper, and then it goes on to develop very general results.  I think it is a very beautiful treatment of the subject; even the classical statements are made much clearer than is usual (in my experience) in more traditional treatments.

Comment: Thanks for sharing that link. It is indeed a very nice exposition. There are some older treatments that go partway there, but I cannot recall them off the top of my head.

Answer (score 6):

My favourite reference on this subject would be the excellent treatment contained in the book "Primes of the form $x^2+ny^2$ by D. A. Cox - [see here](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0471190799)

He gives a lot of details of the historical background (going back to Fermat and Euler) to both binary quadratic forms and the class number problem for quadratic fields. It is not really a textbook, but is very readable with many interesting exercises, and a huge collection of references for further study.

Comment: Thank you very much! I will try to get hold of this book

Comment: For a more modern treatment (but also much much more sophisticated), you might look at J-P, Serre's book "A Course in Arithmetic" - [see here](http://books.google.co.uk/books/about/A_Course_in_Arithmetic.html?id=Ohj9NNk6btUC&redir_esc=y), but this book requires much more by way of algebraic knowledge.

Answer (score 5):

Along with Cox, I like Duncan Buell, *Binary Quadratic Forms* because it does pretty much everything with integral forms, including indefinite forms and those with odd $b$ in $f(x,y) = a x^2 + b x y + c y^2.$ It gives explicit calculations for composition, particularly computer algorithms. see [HERE](http://books.google.com/books?id=qMa8-FDOR8YC&printsec=frontcover&source=gbs_ge_summary_r&cad=0#v=onepage&q&f=false)

Comment: Notice that computations for the composition go back to Gauss, or earlier.

Comment: I have been wondering whether explaining (in possibly somewhat informal style) the connection between QFs and class numbers would make a fine topic for a [blog post](http://math.blogoverflow.com). In that case you would be the logical choice to author it. I guess many members like me have only seen the class group way of thinking about it. The references are there, sure, but still?