# Prerequisites for Dirichlet & Dedekind's Vorlesungen über Zahlentheorie

Tags: elementary-number-theory, algebraic-number-theory

What are the prerequisites for Dirichlet & Dedekind's Vorlesungen über Zahlentheorie?
There is an English translation of this book: P. G. Lejeune Dirichlet, R. Dedekind translated by John Stillwell: Lectures on Number Theory, 1999

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not much at all. In fact, you can probably get by with a working knowledge of high school algebra. This is a accessible work, aimed at a general mathematical audience.

Comment: The book will also apparently answer your questions on Math.SE.

Comment: For the proof of the theorem on primes in arithmetic progression, you will certainly need some calculus, and complex numbers for Dirichlet characters.

Comment: @Matt Then I wonder why most of my questions concerning integral binary quadratic forms are unanswered.

http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/192217/bijection-between-an-ideal-class-group-and-a-set-of-classes-of-binary-quadratic