# Prerequisites: Dirichlet Lectures Number Theory

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, reference-request

I am interested in getting Dirichlet's Lectures in Number Theory but I'm afraid I don't know that much advanced math. Do I need to know things like Determinants for this book? Any list of prerequisites would appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/451773/prerequisites-for-dirichlet-dedekinds-vorlesungen-%C3%BCber-zahlentheorie

Comment: Thank you daOnlyBG. The person who answered it was not correct; the last chapter requires calculus and other mathematics. I do not trust his answer, so I want a more complete one.