# How to compute the class group of an order of a quadratic number field

Tags: algebraic-number-theory, quadratic-forms

Let $K$ be a quadratic number field.
Let $R$ be an order of $K$, i.e. the subring of $K$ which is a free $\mathbb{Z}$-module of rank $2$.Let $D$ be its discriminant.
We use the notation and the result of [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/192217/bijection-between-an-ideal-class-group-and-a-set-of-classes-of-binary-quadratic).
There exists a bijection between $Cl^+(R)$ and the set of classes of primitive binary quadratic forms of discriminant $D$.
So it is natural to ask the following question.

**My question**
How can we compute the ideal class group $G = Cl^+(R)$?
Namely how can we compute the following tasks?

1. Find a set of full representatives of the group $G$.
2. Compute the multiplication table of the group $G$ in terms of the above representatives.

Comment: It is a natural, but obviously hard. We can't even answer this easily, I mean it's really hard, even for a maximal order. Why should it be easier for a general order?