# Algorithm to write an element of $SL_2(\mathbb{Z})$ as a product of $S, T^n$

Tags: group-theory

It is well-known that $SL_2(\mathbb{Z})$ is generated by $S = \left( \begin{array}{ccc}0 & -1 \\1 & 0 \end{array} \right), T = \left( \begin{array}{ccc}1 & 1 \\0 & 1 \end{array} \right)$(e.g. Serre's A Course in Arithmetic).
Let $\sigma \in SL_2(\mathbb{Z})$.
Is there algorithm to explicitly write $\sigma$ as a product of $S, T^n, n \in \mathbb{Z}$?
If yes, how?

Comment: Isn't the algorithm basically just the Euclidean algorithm?

Comment: @AlexYoucis I have no idea how the Euclidean algorithm can be used to solve the problem.

Comment: I'm not sure if you can noodle around with stuff to only need to use one $S$, but look here: http://www.math.uconn.edu/~kconrad/blurbs/grouptheory/SL(2,Z).pdf