# How to determine whether a given ideal of an order of a quadratic number field is invertible or not

Tags: algebraic-number-theory

Let $K$ be a quadratic number field.
Let $R$ be an order of $K$, i.e. a subring of $K$ which is a free $\mathbb{Z}$-module of rank $2$.
Let $D$ be the discriminant of $R$.
Let $x_1,\cdots, x_n$ be a sequence of elements of $R$.
We denote by $[x_1,\cdots,x_n]$ the $\mathbb{Z}$-submodule of $R$ generated by $x_1,\cdots, x_n$.
By [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/546281/on-a-certain-basis-of-an-order-of-a-quadratic-number-field), $R = [1, \omega]$, where $\omega = \frac{(D + \sqrt D)}{2}$.
Let $I$ be an ideal of $R$.
If there exists an $R$-submodule $J$ of $K$ such that $IJ = R$, $I$ is called invertible. 
It is easy to see that $J$ is uniquely determined by $I$.
It is also easy to see that $J$ is a $\mathbb{Z}$-free submodule of $K$ of rank $2$.
$J$ is denoted by $I^{-1}$.

I would like to determine whether a given non-zero ideal $I$ of $R$ is invertible or not.
By [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/552516/canonical-basis-of-an-ideal-of-a-quadratic-order), there exist unique rational integers $a, b, c$ such that $I = [a, b + c\omega], a \gt 0, c \gt 0, 0 \le b \lt a, a \equiv 0$ (mod $c$), $b \equiv 0$ (mod $c$).
If $c = 1$, we say $I$ is a primitive ideal.
Let $a = ca'$, $b = cb'$.
Then $I = cJ$, where $J = [a', b' + \omega]$.
Clearly $J$ is a primitive ideal.
$I$ is invertible if and only if $J$ is invertible.
Hence we can assume that $I$ is primitive.

**My question**
Let $I = [a, r + \omega]$ be a primitive ideal of $R$, where $a \gt 0, r$ are rational integers.
How can we solve the following problems?

1. Determine whether $I$ is invertible or not.
2. If $I$ is invertible, find a free $\mathbb{Z}$-basis of $I^{-1}$.

Comment: What's the reason for the downvote? Unless you tell me, I cannot improve the question.

Answer (score 0):

Let $\sigma$ be the unique non-identity automorphism of $K/\mathbb{Q}$.
We denote $\sigma(\alpha)$ by $\alpha'$ for $\alpha \in K$.

Let $I = [a, r + \omega]$ be a primitive ideal of $R$, where $a \gt 0, r$ are rational integers.
Let $\theta = (r + \omega)/a$.
The minimal polynomial of $\theta$ over $\mathbb{Q}$ is $x^2 - px + q = (x - \theta)(x - \theta')$.
where $p = \theta + \theta', q = \theta\theta'$.
Let us compute $p$ and $q$.
$p = (r + \omega)/a + (r + \omega')/a = (2r + D)/a$.
$q = (r + \omega)(r + \omega')/a^2 = (r^2 + rD + (D^2 - D)/4)/a^2$.
Hence $\theta$ is a root of a polynomial $ax^2 + bx + c$, where $b = -ap = -(2r + D),
c = aq = (r^2 + rD + (D^2 - D)/4)/a$.
By [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/553942/condition-for-a-b-omega-to-be-the-canonical-basis-of-an-ideal-of-a-quadrat), $N(r + \omega) = (r + \omega)(r + \omega')$ is divisinle by $a$.
Hence $c$ is an integer.
Note that $(-b + \sqrt D)/2 = r + \omega$.
The discriminant of this polynomial is $b^2 - 4ac = (2r + D)^2 - 4(r^2 + rD + (D^2 - D)/4) = D$.
By [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/191933/a-binary-quadratic-form-and-an-ideal-of-an-order-of-a-quadratic-number-field), $I = [a,\ (-b + \sqrt D)/2]$ is invertible if and only if gcd$(a, b, c) = 1$.
By Lemma 2 of my ansewer to [the question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/191933/a-binary-quadratic-form-and-an-ideal-of-an-order-of-a-quadratic-number-field), 
$(R : I) = \mathbb{Z} + \mathbb{Z}\frac{(b + \sqrt D)}{2a}$.
Suppose $I$ is invertible.
By [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/546768/characterization-of-an-invertible-module), $I^{-1} = (R : I) = \mathbb{Z} + \mathbb{Z}\frac{(b + \sqrt D)}{2a}$.