# Determination of the prime ideals lying over an odd prime in a quadratic order

Tags: algebraic-number-theory, alternative-proof

We need some notation before we state the problem.
Let $K$ be a quadratic number field, $d$ its discriminant.
Let $R$ be an order of $K$, i.e. a subring of $K$ which is a free $\mathbb{Z}$-module of rank $2$.
Let $D$ its discriminant.
Let $x_1,\cdots, x_n$ be a sequence of elements of $R$.
We denote by $[x_1,\cdots,x_n]$ the $\mathbb{Z}$-submodule of $R$ generated by $x_1,\cdots, x_n$.
By [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/546281/on-a-certain-basis-of-an-order-of-a-quadratic-number-field), $R = [1, \omega]$, where $\omega = \frac{(D + \sqrt D)}{2}$.
Let $\sigma$ be the unique non-identity automorphism of $K/\mathbb{Q}$.
We denote $\sigma(\alpha)$ by $\alpha'$ for $\alpha \in R$.
We denote $\sigma(I)$ by $I'$ for an ideal $I$ of $R$.
Let $f$ be the order of $\mathcal{O}_K/R$ as a $\mathbb{Z}$-module.
Then $D = f^2d$ (see [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/528122/on-orders-of-a-quadratic-number-field)).
Let $p$ be a prime number such that gcd$(p, f) = 1$.
Then $pR$ is regular by [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/556643/criterion-on-whether-a-given-ideal-of-a-quadratic-order-is-regular-or-not).
Hence $pR$ is uniquely decomposed as a product of regular prime ideals by [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/158876/ideal-class-group-of-a-one-dimensional-noetherian-domain).
So it is natural to ask how it is decomposed.
I came up with the following proposition.

**Proposition**
Let $K, R$, etc. be as above.
Let $p$ be an odd prime number such that gcd$(p, f) = 1$.

**Case 1** $D$ is divisible by $p$.

$P = [p, \omega]$ is a prime ideal and $pR = P^2$.
Moreover $P = P'$.

**Case 2** gcd$(D, p) = 1$ and $D$ is quadratic residue modulo $p$.

Let $b, b'$ be solutions of $(2x + d)^2 \equiv d$ (mod $p$) such that $b - b'$ is not divisible by $p$.
Then $P = [p, b + \omega]$ and $P' = [p, b' + \omega]$ are distinct prime ideals and $pR = PP'$.

**Case 3** gcd$(D, p) = 1$ and $D$ is quadratic non-residue modulo $p$.

$pR$ is a prime ideal.

**Method of my proof**
I used the result of [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/553942/condition-for-a-b-omega-to-be-the-canonical-basis-of-an-ideal-of-a-quadrat).

**My question**
How do you prove the proposition?
I would like to know other proofs based on different ideas from mine.
I welcome you to provide as many different proofs as possible.
I wish the proofs would be detailed enough for people who have basic knowledge of introductory algebraic number theory to be able to understand.

Answer (score 0):

Let $P$ be a prime ideal of $R$ lying over $p$.
Since $P \cap \mathbb{Z} = p\mathbb{Z}$, by [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/552516/canonical-basis-of-an-ideal-of-a-quadratic-order), 
there exist integers $b, c$ such that $P = [p, b + c\omega],
c \gt 0, p \equiv 0$ (mod $c$), $b \equiv 0$ (mod $c$).
Then $c = 1$ or $p$.
Suppose $c = 1$.
Then $N_{K/\mathbb{Q}}(b + \omega) \equiv 0$ (mod $p$)(see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/553942/condition-for-a-b-omega-to-be-the-canonical-basis-of-an-ideal-of-a-quadrat)).
$N_{K/\mathbb{Q}}(b + \omega) = (b + \omega)(b + \omega') = \frac{2b + D + \sqrt D}{2}\frac{2b + D - \sqrt D}{2}
= \frac{(2b + D)^2 - D}{4}$.
Hence $(2b + D)^2 - D \equiv 0$ (mod $p$).
Hence $(2b + D)^2 \equiv D$ (mod $p$).

Suppose $c = p$.
Then $P = [p, p\omega] = pR$.

**Case 1** $D$ is divisible by $p$.

Suppose $P = [p, b + \omega]$.
Then by the above argument, $(2b + D)^2 \equiv D$ (mod $p$).
Since $D \equiv 0$ (mod $p$), $4b^2 \equiv 0$ (mod $p$).
Since $p$ is odd, $b \equiv 0$ (mod $p$).
Hence $P = [p, \omega]$.

We first claim that $P = [p, \omega]$ is an ideal.
By [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/553942/condition-for-a-b-omega-to-be-the-canonical-basis-of-an-ideal-of-a-quadrat), It suffces to prove that $N_{K/\mathbb{Q}}(\omega) = D(D - 1)/4$ is divisible by $p$.

By [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/191830/discriminant-of-a-binary-quadratic-form-and-an-order-of-a-quadratic-number-field), $D \equiv 0$ (mod $4$) or $D \equiv 1$ (mod $4$).
Suppose $D \equiv 0$ (mod $4$).
Let $D = 4m$.
Then $D(D - 1)/4 = m(D - 1)$.
Since $D$ is divisible by $p$, $m$ is divisible by $p$.
Hence $D(D - 1)/4$ is divisible by $p$.

Suppose $D \equiv 1$ (mod $4$).
Then $D(D - 1)/4$ is divisible by $p$.

Hence $P$ is an ideal.
Since $N(P) = p$, $P$ is a prime ideal.

Since $\omega + \omega' = D$, $\omega' \in P$.
Hence $P = [p, \omega] = [p, \omega'] = P'$.
Since gcd$(p, f) = 1$, $P$ is a regular ideal by [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/556643/criterion-on-whether-a-given-ideal-of-a-quadratic-order-is-regular-or-not).
Hence $P^2 = PP' = pR$ by [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/562238/norm-of-a-regular-ideal-of-an-order-of-an-algebraic-number-field-which-is-galois).

**Case 2** gcd$(D, p) = 1$ and $D$ is quadratic residue modulo $p$.

As we see in the beginning, $N_{K/\mathbb{Q}}(b + \omega) = \frac{(2b + D)^2 - D}{4}$.
Hence $4N(b + \omega) = (2b + D)^2 - D$.
Since $(2b + D)^2 - D \equiv 0$ (mod $p$) and $p$ is odd, $N_{K/\mathbb{Q}}(b + \omega)$ is divisible by $p$.
Hence $P = [p, b + \omega]$ is an ideal of $R$ by [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/553942/condition-for-a-b-omega-to-be-the-canonical-basis-of-an-ideal-of-a-quadrat).
Hence $P' = [p, b + \omega']$ is also an ideal of $R$.
Let $\theta = b + \omega$.
Then $PP' = (p, \theta)(p, \theta') = (p^2, p\theta, p\theta', \theta\theta') \subset pR$.
Since $D = f^2d$ and gcd$(D, p) = 1$, gcd$(f, p) = 1$.
Hence $P$ and $P'$ are regular by [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/556643/criterion-on-whether-a-given-ideal-of-a-quadratic-order-is-regular-or-not).
Hence $N(PP') = N(P)N(P') = p^2$ by [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/562238/norm-of-a-regular-ideal-of-an-order-of-an-algebraic-number-field-which-is-galois).
Since $N(pR) = p^2$, $PP' = pR$.

We will show that $P \ne P'$.
Since $\omega + \omega' = D$, $P' = [p, b + \omega'] = [p, b + D - \omega]$.
Suppose $P = P'$.
Then $(b + \omega) + (b + D - \omega) =  2b + D \in P$.
Hence $2b + D \equiv 0$ (mod $p$).
Since $(2b + D)^2 \equiv D$ (mod $p$), $D \equiv 0$ (mod $p$).
This is a contradiction.

It remains to prove that $P' = [p, b' + \omega]$.
$P' = [p, b + D - \omega] = [p, -b - D + \omega]$.
$N(-b - D + \omega) = \frac{-2b - D + \sqrt D}{2}\frac{-2b - D - \sqrt D}{2}
= \frac{(-2b - D)^2 - D}{4}$.
Hence $\frac{(-2b - D)^2 - D}{4}$ is divisible by $p$ by [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/553942/condition-for-a-b-omega-to-be-the-canonical-basis-of-an-ideal-of-a-quadrat).
Since $p$ is odd, $(-2b - D)^2 \equiv D$ (mod $p$).
Hence $-b - D$ is a solution of $(2x + D)^2 \equiv D$ (mod $p$).
It suffices to prove that $b$ is not congruent to $-b - D$ modulo $p$.
Suppose $b \equiv -b - D$ (mod $p$).
Then $2b + D \equiv 0$ (mod $p$).
Since $(2b + D)^2 \equiv D$ (mod p), $D \equiv 0$ (mod $p$).
This is a contradiction.

**Case 3** gcd$(D, p) = 1$ and $D$ is quadratic non-residue modulo $p$.

Let $P$ be a prime ideal lying over $p$.
By the argument in the beginning, $P = [p, p\omega] = pR$.