# Determination of the prime ideals lying over $2$ in a quadratic order

Tags: algebraic-number-theory, alternative-proof

Let $K$ be a quadratic number field.
Let $R$ be an order of $K$, $D$ its discriminant.
By [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/546281/on-a-certain-basis-of-an-order-of-a-quadratic-number-field), $1, \omega = \frac{(D + \sqrt D)}{2}$ is a basis of $R$ as a $\mathbb{Z}$-module.

Let $x_1,\cdots, x_n$ be a sequence of elements of $R$.
We denote by $[x_1,\cdots,x_n]$ the $\mathbb{Z}$-submodule of $R$ generated by $x_1,\cdots, x_n$.

**My Question**
Is the following proposition correct?
If yes, how do you prove it?

**Proposition**

**Case 1** $D$ is even.

$P = [2, \omega]$ is a prime ideal and $2R = P^2$.

**Case 2** $D \equiv 1$ (mod $8$).

$P = [p, \omega]$ and $P' = [p, 1 + \omega]$ are distinct prime ideals and $2R = PP'$.
Moreover $P' = \sigma(P)$, where $\sigma$ is the unique non-identity automorphism of $K/\mathbb{Q}$.

**Case 3** $D \equiv 5$ (mod $8$).

$2R$ is a prime ideal.

Comment: I would like to point out the following policy of StackExchange because it doesn't seem to be well-known and some users seem to dislike a question to which the poster already knows the answer.
`[It’s also perfectly fine to ask and answer your own question, as long as you pretend you’re on Jeopardy! ? phrase it in the form of a question.
To be crystal clear, it is not merely OK to ask and answer your own question, it is explicitly encouraged.]`
http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/07/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/

Answer (score 4):

Since $\omega = (D + \sqrt{D})/2$ has minimal polynomial equal to $x^2 - D x + D(D-1)/4,$ we may write $R = \mathbb Z[x]/(x^2 - Dx - D(D-1)/4),$ and so $R/2R = 
\mathbb F_2[x]/(x^2 - D x - D(D-1)/4)$ (identify $\omega$ with the image of $x$).

If $D$ is even (and hence a multiple of $4$), the polynomial $x^2 - D x - D(D-1)/4 $ is congruent to $x^2 + 1 = (x+1)^2$ mod $2$.

If $D \equiv 5 \bmod 8$, then this polynomial is congruent to $x^2 + x + 1$ (an irreducible polynomial) mod $2$.

If $D \equiv 1 \bmod 8,$ then this polynomial is congruent to $x^2 + x = x(x+1)$ mod $2$.

In the first case we see that $(2) = (x,2)^2$, in the second case that $(2)$ is prime, and in third case that $(2) = (x,2)(x+1,2)$.

This proves the proposition. (Actually, the way the proposition is phrased, you have to check that the $R$-modules with the indicated generators, which is what I am writing, are the same at the $\mathbb Z$-modules with these generators.  This is straightforward.)

Comment: `[If $D$ is even (and hence a multiple of $4$), the polynomial $x^2 - D x - D(D-1)/4 $ is congruent to $x^2 + 1 = (x+1)^2$ mod $2$.]`
Dear Matt E, you mean it is congruent to $x^2$ or $(x+1)^2$ mod $2$, right?

Comment: @MakotoKato: Dear Makoto, Yes, that's right.  Regards,

Comment: Dear Matt E, I'm afraid I don't understand why $(2) = (x,2)^2$ in the first case.
It seems that $(2) = (x,2)^2$ or $(x + 1, 2)^2$ according $D/4$ is even or odd.

Comment: @MakotoKato: Dear Makoto, I think that you're correct.  E.g. if $D = -4$, then $\omega = -2 + i,$ and $(2) = (-1+i)^2 = (1 + \omega, 2)^2,$ while if $D = -8,$ then $\omega = -4 + \sqrt{-2},$ and so $(2,\omega)$ = (2,\sqrt{-2}) = (\sqrt{-2}),$ and so in this case $(2,\omega)^2 = (2)$.  So I think the statement when $D$ is even has to be modified to take this into account.  Regards,

Answer (score -1):

I realized after I posted this question that the proposition is not correct.
I will prove a corrected version of the proposition.

We need some notation.
Let $\sigma$ be the unique non-identity automorphism of $K/\mathbb{Q}$.
We denote $\sigma(\alpha)$ by $\alpha'$ for $\alpha \in R$.
We denote $\sigma(I)$ by $I'$ for an ideal $I$ of $R$.

**Proposition**
Let $K$ be a quadratic number field, $d$ its discriminant.
Let $R$ be an order of $K$, $D$ its discriminant.
By [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/191830/discriminant-of-a-binary-quadratic-form-and-an-order-of-a-quadratic-number-field), $D \equiv 0$ or $1$ (mod $4$).
By [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/546281/on-a-certain-basis-of-an-order-of-a-quadratic-number-field), $1, \omega = \frac{(D + \sqrt D)}{2}$ is a basis of $R$ as a $\mathbb{Z}$-module.
Let $f$ be the order of $\mathcal{O}_K/R$ as a $\mathbb{Z}$-module.
Then $D = f^2d$ by [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/528122/on-orders-of-a-quadratic-number-field).
**We suppose gcd$(f, 2) = 1$**.

**Case 1** $D$ is even.

Since $D \equiv 0$ (mod $4$), $D \equiv 0, 4$ (mod $8$).
If $D \equiv 0$ (mod $8$), let $P = [2, \omega]$.
If $D \equiv 4$ (mod $8$), let $P = [2, 1 + \omega]$.
Then $P$ is a prime ideal and $2R = P^2$.
Moreover $P = P'$.

**Case 2** $D \equiv 1$ (mod $8$).

$P = [p, \omega]$ and $P' = [p, 1 + \omega]$ are distinct prime ideals and $2R = PP'$.

**Case 3** $D \equiv 5$ (mod $8$).

$2R$ is a prime ideal.

We need the following lemmas to prove the proposition.

**Lemma 1**
Let $K, R, D, \omega$ be as in the proposition.
Let $P = [2, b + \omega]$, where $b$ is a rational integer.
Then $P$ is an ideal if and only if $(2b + D)^2 - D \equiv 0$ (mod $8$).
Moreover, if $P$ satisfies this condition, $P$ is a prime ideal.

Proof:
By [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/553942/condition-for-a-b-omega-to-be-the-canonical-basis-of-an-ideal-of-a-quadrat), $P = [2, b + \omega]$ is an ideal if and only if $N_{K/\mathbb{Q}}(b + \omega) \equiv 0$ (mod $2$).
$N_{K/\mathbb{Q}}(b + \omega) = (b + \omega)(b + \omega') = \frac{2b + D + \sqrt D}{2}\frac{2b + D - \sqrt D}{2}
= \frac{(2b + D)^2 - D}{4}$.
Hence $P$ is an ideal if and only if $(2b + D)^2 - D \equiv 0$ (mod $8$)
Since $N(P) = 2$, $P$ is a prime ideal.

**Lemma 2**
Let $K, R, D, \omega$ be as in the proposition.
Suppose gcd$(f, 2) = 1$ and there exist no prime ideals of the form $P = [2, b + \omega]$,
where $b$ is an integer.
Then $2R$ is a prime ideal of $R$.

Proof:
Let $P$ be a prime ideal of $R$ lying over $2$.
Then $P \cap \mathbb{Z} = 2\mathbb{Z}$.
By [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/552516/canonical-basis-of-an-ideal-of-a-quadratic-order), there exist integers $b, c$ such that $P = [2, b + c\omega],
c \gt 0, 2 \equiv 0$ (mod $c$), $b \equiv 0$ (mod $c$).
Then $c = 1$ or $2$.
By the assumption, $c = 2$.
Hence $P = [2, 2\omega] = 2R$.

**Proof of the proposition**

**Case 1** $D$ is even.

Let $P = [2, b + \omega]$, where $b$ is an integer.
We may assume that $b = 0$ or $1$.
By Lemma 1, $P$ is a prime ideal if and only if $(2b + D)^2 - D \equiv 0$ (mod $8$).

Suppose $D \equiv 0$ (mod $8$).
Then $(2b + D)^2 - D \equiv 0$ (mod $8$) if and only if $b = 0$.
Hence $P = [2, \omega]$ is an ideal of $R$.
$P' = [2, \omega'] = [2, D - \omega] = [2, -\omega] = [2, \omega] = P$.

Suppose $D \equiv 4$ (mod $8$).
Then $(2b + D)^2 - D \equiv 0$ (mod $8$) if and only if $b = 1$.
Hence $P = [2, 1 + \omega]$ is an ideal of $R$.
$P' = [2, 1 + \omega'] = [2, 1 + D - \omega] = [2, -1 - D + \omega] = [2, 1 + \omega] = P$.

Since gcd$(f, 2) = 1$, $P$ is regular by [this quuestion](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/556643/criterion-on-whether-a-given-ideal-of-a-quadratic-order-is-regular-or-not).
Hence $PP' = 2R$ by [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/562238/norm-of-a-regular-ideal-of-an-order-of-an-algebraic-number-field-which-is-galois).

**Case 2** $D \equiv 1$ (mod $8$).

If $b = 0, 1$, then
$(2b + D)^2 - D \equiv (2b + 1)^2 - 1 \equiv 0$ (mod $8$).
Hence, by Lemma 1, $P = [2, \omega]$ and $Q = [2, 1 + \omega]$ are prime ideals of $R$.
$P' = [2, \omega'] = [2, D - \omega] = [2, - D + \omega] = [2, 1 + \omega] = Q$.
Since gcd$(f, 2) = 1$, $P$ is regular by [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/556643/criterion-on-whether-a-given-ideal-of-a-quadratic-order-is-regular-or-not).
Hence $PP' = 2R$ by [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/562238/norm-of-a-regular-ideal-of-an-order-of-an-algebraic-number-field-which-is-galois).

**Case 3** $D \equiv 5$ (mod $8$).

Consider the following congruence equation. 
$(2b + D)^2 - D \equiv (2b + 5)^2 - 5 \equiv 0$ (mod $8$).
Since $b$ does not satisfy this congruence equation when $b = 0$ or $1$,
there exist no ideals of the form $[2, b + \omega]$.
Hence $2R$ is a prime ideal by Lemma 2.