# The number of genera of binary quadratic forms of given discriminant

Tags: elementary-number-theory, algebraic-number-theory

Is the following proposition true?
If yes, how do we prove it?

**Proposition**
Let $D$ be a non-square integer such that $D \equiv 0$ (mod $4$) or $D \equiv 1$ (mod $4$).
Let $\Phi_1,\dots,\Phi_{\mu}$ be [the system of genus characters](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/191344/the-system-of-genus-characters-determined-by-a-binary-quadratic-form) of discriminant $D$.
Then the number of [genera](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/192819/the-narrow-class-group-of-an-order-of-a-quadratic-field-and-the-genera-of-binary) of discriminant $D$ is $2^{\mu - 1}$.