# A condition for an odd integer to be properly represented by a primitive binary quadratic form

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Let $f = ax^2 + bxy + cy^2$ be a binary quadratic form over $\mathbb{Z}$.
We say $D = b^2 - 4ac$ is the discriminant of $f$.
It is easy to see that $D \equiv 0$ (mod $4$) or $D \equiv 1$ (mod $4$).
If $D$ is a non-square integer and gcd$(a, b, c) = 1$, we say $f$ is primitive.
Let $m$ be an integer.
If $m = ax^2 + bxy + cy^2$ has a solution in $\mathbb{Z}^2$, we say $m$ is represented by $F$.
If $m = ax^2 + bxy + cy^2$ has a solution $(s, t)$ such that gcd$(s, t) = 1$,
we say $m$ is properly represented by $f$.

Suppose $m$ is properly represented by $ax^2 + bxy + cy^2$.
Then $D$ is a quadratic residue modulo $m$ by [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/191198/quadratic-residues-and-representations-of-integers-by-a-binary-quadratic-form).

Now I would like to ask if the converse holds.
Namely, is the following proposition correct?
If yes, how do we prove it?

**Proposition**
Let $D$ be a non-square integer such that $D \equiv 0$ (mod $4$) or $D \equiv 1$ (mod $4$).
Let $m$ be an odd integer such that gcd$(m, D) = 1$.
Suppose $D$ is a quadratic residue modulo $m$.
Then there exists a primitive form $f = ax^2 + bxy + cy^2$ of discriminant $D$
and $m$ is properly represented by $f$.

Comment: I would like to point out the following policy of StackExchange because it doesn't seem to be well-known and some users seem to dislike a question to which the poster already knows the answer.
`[It’s also perfectly fine to ask and answer your own question, as long as you pretend you’re on Jeopardy! — phrase it in the form of a question.
To be crystal clear, it is not merely OK to ask and answer your own question, it is explicitly encouraged.]`
http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/07/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/

Answer (score 2):

Since $D$ is a quadratic residue modulo $m$, there exists an integer $b$ such that $D \equiv b^2 \pmod m$.
Since $m$ is odd, $b + m$ is odd when $b$ is even.
Similarly $b + m$ is even when $b$ is odd.
Hence we may assume that $D$ and $b$ have the same parity.
Then

If $D \equiv 0 \pmod 4$, $D - b^2 \equiv 0 \pmod 4$.

If $D \equiv 1 \pmod 4$, $D - b^2 \equiv 0 \pmod 4$.

In either case, $D \equiv b^2 \pmod {4m}$.
Hence there exists an integer $c$ such that $b^2 - D = 4mc$.
Then the discriminant of the form $f = mx^2 + bxy + cy^2$ is $D$.
Let $d = \gcd (m, b, c)$.
Since $m$ and $D = b^2 - 4mc$ are both divisible by $d$, $d$ must be $1$.
Hence $f$ is primitive.
Since $m = f(1, 0)$, $m$ is properly represented by $f$.