# How to prove that there exist infinitely many integer solutions to the equation $x^2-ny^2=1$ without Algebraic Number Theory

Tags: algebraic-number-theory, diophantine-equations

I learned in my Intro Algebraic Number Theory class that there exist infinitely many integer pairs $(x,y)$ that satisfy the hyperbola $x^2-ny^2=1$; just consider that there are infinitely many units in $\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{n})}$, and their norms satisfy the desired equation. Although this is a nice connection, I was wondering if it is possible to reach the solution without using high-powered Algebraic Number Theory. And more generally, does the same result hold true for $x^2-ny^2=k$ where $k$ is any integer? And how would one solve that?

Comment: You need to assume that $n$ is not a perfect square

Comment: See the "History" section here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pell%27s_equation. There are ancient proofs that there are infinitely many solutions!

Comment: I see...some good old-fashioned Number Theory! I need to read up more on this. Amazing that this was solved so long ago...

Comment: Translate back the result from ANT! Assume that $(x,y)$ is a solution. Therefore $u=x+ y\sqrt n$ has norm $1$. Therefore so does $u^\ell=x_\ell+y_\ell\sqrt n$. Therefore $(x_\ell,y_\ell)$ is also a solution. You get the numbers $(x_\ell,y_\ell)$ from the binomial formula. For example, $x_2=x^2+ny^2$, $y_2=2xy$, $x_3=x^3+3nxy^2$, $y_3=3yx^2+ny^3$ et cetera. Essentially you are combining the multiplicativity of the norm (can be proven without ANT) and the binomial theorem. So w/o any real ANT.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen : I see that the essential method you're using to generate the infinite solns is not ANT but rather NT; but do you mean the use of the norm is not ANT? What is it then, just general Abstract-Alg ?

Comment: To be honest, IDK. Wherever you draw the line. I was just trying to approach it one way. To a great extent it is a matter of taste. That approach does not use ANT in the sense that it doesn't invoke Dirichlet's theorem on units and such. Suit yourself, and enjoy the problems!

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen : yeah, well-put. Dirichlet's Theorem is knee-deep in the ANT ocean by anyone's standards, and use of the norm is more like dipping your pinky in a puddle.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

EDIT: there have been many comments on my answers asking about the use of the word **automorph**. This is a real thing! I did not just make up a word. For a fixed quadratic form, you get a **group of integral automorphs**. In just two variables, there is a good recipe for finding all. In three or more variables, it is a mess. Sometimes this is called the **orthogonal group** of the form, or the **isometry group**. If you think about finding all real solutions of the basic matrix equation, $A^T F A = F,$ where $F$ is a symmetric matrix associated with a quadratic form, the group part may be clearer, especially when $F=I.$ If $F$ has all rational entries, it is reasonable to solve this with rational or $p$-adic entries in $A.$ Finally, when $F,$ or at least $2 F,$ has integer entries, it is reasonable to ask about $A$ with integer entries.

I would like people to know more about this. In dimension 2 this has considerable overlap with algebraic number theory for quadratic fields. In dimension 3 or more, the theory of quadratic forms, in this case indefinite forms, separates from algebraic number theory to a considerable extent.

ORIGINAL:Given nontrivial $\tau^2 - n \sigma^2 = 1,$ we get

$$ \left(  \begin{array}{cc}
  \tau  &  \sigma  \\
   n \sigma   &  \tau  
\end{array} 
\right)
 \left(  \begin{array}{cc}
  1  &  0  \\
   0   &  -n  
\end{array} 
\right)
 \left(  \begin{array}{cc}
  \tau  &  n \sigma  \\
   \sigma   &  \tau  
\end{array} 
\right) =
 \left(  \begin{array}{cc}
  1  &  0  \\
   0   &  -n  
\end{array} 
\right).
$$

As a result, if $x^2 - n y^2 = k,$ then we get the same $k$ for 
$$ \left(  \begin{array}{cc}
  \tau  & n \sigma  \\
    \sigma   &  \tau  
\end{array} 
\right)
 \left(  \begin{array}{c}
  x    \\
   y 
\end{array} 
\right)
  =
 \left(  \begin{array}{c}
  \tau x +  n \sigma y  \\
   \sigma x + \tau y     
\end{array} 
\right).
$$

This 2 by 2 matrix is called an automorph of the quadratic form.

Every indefinite form $f(x,y) = a x^2 + b x y + c y^2$ where $\Delta = b^2 - 4 a c$ is positive but not a square, has such an automorph, leading to infinitely many solutions. Indeed, given $\tau^2 - \Delta \sigma^2 = 4,$ we get

$$ \left(  \begin{array}{cc}
  \frac{\tau - b \sigma}{2}  &  a \sigma  \\
   -c \sigma   &    \frac{\tau + b \sigma}{2}   
\end{array} 
\right)
 \left(  \begin{array}{cc}
  a  &  \frac{b}{2}  \\
   \frac{b}{2}    &  c    
\end{array} 
\right)
 \left(  \begin{array}{cc}
  \frac{\tau - b \sigma}{2}  &  -c \sigma  \\
   a \sigma   &    \frac{\tau + b \sigma}{2}  
\end{array} 
\right) =
 \left(  \begin{array}{cc}
  a  &  \frac{b}{2}  \\
   \frac{b}{2}    &  c  
\end{array} 
\right).
$$ 
Therefore, if we have $ a x^2 + b x y + c y^2 = k,$ we have another with
 $$
 \left(  \begin{array}{cc}
  \frac{\tau - b \sigma}{2}  &  -c \sigma  \\
   a \sigma   &    \frac{\tau + b \sigma}{2}  
\end{array} 
\right) 
 \left(  \begin{array}{c}
  x    \\
   y 
\end{array} 
\right)
  =
 \left(  \begin{array}{c}
   \frac{\tau - b \sigma}{2} x - c \sigma y  \\
   a \sigma x +  \frac{\tau + b \sigma}{2} y     
\end{array} 
\right).
$$

For previous answers in which I show how to use an automorph, see
[Solve the Diophantine equation $ 3x^2 - 2y^2 =1 $](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/181758/solve-the-diophantine-equation-3x2-2y2-1)

[How to find solutions of $x^2-3y^2=-2$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/228356/how-to-find-solutions-of-x2-3y2-2)

Books: H.E.Rose, *A Course in Number Theory*, chapter 9, section 3, especially pages 162-164 in the first edition.

Thomas W. Cusick and Mary E. Flahive, *The Markoff and Lagrange Spectra* appendix 3 on pages 91-92.

Duncan A. Buell, *Binary Quadratic Forms* chapter 3, section 2, pages 31-34.

William J. LeVeque, *Topics in Number Theory*, volume 2, pages 24-29.  The two volumes are available as a one volume paperback, [LeVeque Book](http://store.doverpublications.com/0486425398.html)

Leonard Eugene Dickson, *Introduction to the Theory of Numbers*, especially pages 111-112.

Comment: I'm not really sure what you're doing, never seen this before.

Comment: @Coffee_Table, I'm editing in some previous problems where I did this, some books.

Comment: how lovely, nice resources.

Answer (score 1):

See Wikipedia on [Pell's equation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pell%27s_equation), also [MathWorld](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/PellEquation.html).

If there's one solution with $x,y\ge1$ then see Brahmagupta's method or the section "Additional solutions from the fundamental solution."

If $(x_1,y_1)$ and $(x_2,y_2)$ are solutions then $(x_1 x_2+n y_1 y_2,x_1y_2+x_2y_1)$ is another larger solution.

If $n$ is not a square then there's always a solution (and hence infinitely many), see MathWorld for how you can find it from a continued fraction expansion.

For $x^2-ny^2=k$ the same argument can get you infinitely many solutions given a fundamental one, but whether or not one exists is more complicated.